# how to pass window handle to c++ win32 dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, dll

I have one project which capture images from multiple cameras which is in C++ .I want to   use that project in my new project which is in C#.I had made dll of that project.My question is ,how can i use that dll in my project.I know by passing  window handle to C++ dll we can use it but i dont know how to do it  and what changes should i make in dll.

Please forgive ,if it is foolish question.

Comment: i have search a lot and i got answers also but i want to know ,in dll how to add function that will get window handle from C#

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem as you and this article helped me.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx

To pass the handle, you can add another function in C++ end. Something like,

(in the header)
`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void SetParent(HWND hWnd);`

To use the SetParent in C#

```
 class Program
 {
    ...

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void SetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

    public void testMethod()
    {
           ...
           IntPtr getAddress = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "SetParent");
           ...
           SetParent setParent = (SetParent)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(getAddress, typeof(SetParent));
           setParent(this.Handle);
           ...       
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ project is already in a DLL you can call any functions that it exports using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  You will have to declare the method in your C# assembly as shown below, but then you can call it like a standard static method.

```
[DllImport("YourDllsName.dll")]
public static extern bool FunctionThatAWindowHandleAndReturnsBool(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Depending on the types of parameters that your C++ DLL's functions take the [marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the .Net datatypes to C data types can get complicated.

Comment: could you tell me how should i do that to get window handle in dll

Comment: Your C++ DLL must have a function that you use to pass it a window handle.  You need to write a P/Invoke definition for that function as above and call it.  You need to know your C++ DLL's API to know what functions to call.

Comment: Can you tell me How to pass handle of main window to C++ dll